# How to blur a .pgm file?

Tags: c, linux, windows, blur, pgm

I've written this code, which is supposed to blur a .pgm file. Works perfectly on Linux, but it gives a wrong result on Windows. The program should be run like this: "filter.exe enb.pgm enb_filtered.pgm qs 3", where the 4th argument can be qs/cnt/ins, depending on what sorting algorithm wants the user to use, while the 5th one it's an odd number and gives the width of the blurring window (it should go at least until 21). 1st argument is our .exe, the 2nd one is the initial image, while the 3rd one is the final image. On Linux, the result is the expected one, while on Windows the enb.filtered.pgm file is all black and it has wrong dimensions. Can you, guys, help me?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

#define HI(num) (((num) & 0x0000FF00) >> 8)
#define LO(num) ((num) & 0x000000FF)

typedef struct _PGMData {
    int row;
    int col;
    int max_gray;
    int **matrix;
} PGMData;

void quick_sort (int *a, int n) {
    int i, j, p, t;
    if (n < 2)
        return;
    p = a[n / 2];
    for (i = 0, j = n - 1;; i++, j--) {
        while (a[i] < p)
            i++;
        while (p < a[j])
            j--;
        if (i >= j)
            break;
        t = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = t;
    }
    quick_sort(a, i);
    quick_sort(a + i, n - i);
}

void insertion_sort (int *a, int n) {
    int i, j, t;
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        t = a[i];
        for (j = i; j > 0 && t < a[j - 1]; j--) {
            a[j] = a[j - 1];
        }
        a[j] = t;
    }
}

void counting_sort(int *array, int n)
{
    int i, j, k, min, max, *count;

    min = max = array[0];
    for(i=1; i < n; i++) {
        if ( array[i] < min ) {
          min = array[i];
        }
        else if ( array[i] > max ) {
            max = array[i];
        }
    }

    count = (int *)calloc(max - min + 1, sizeof(int));
    for(i = 0, k = 0; i < n; i++) {
        count[array[i] - min]++;
    }
    for(i = min; i <= max; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < count[i - min]; j++) {
            array[k++] = i;
        }
    }
    free(count);
}

int **allocate_dynamic_matrix(int row, int col)
{
    int **ret_val;
    int i;

    ret_val = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int *) * row);
    if (ret_val == NULL) {
        perror("memory allocation failure");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < row; ++i) {
        ret_val[i] = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * col);
        if (ret_val[i] == NULL) {
            perror("memory allocation failure");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    return ret_val;
}

void deallocate_dynamic_matrix(int **matrix, int row)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < row; ++i)
        free(matrix[i]);
    free(matrix);
}

void SkipComments(FILE *fp)
{
    int ch;
    char line[100];

    while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF && isspace(ch))
        ;
    if (ch == '#') {
        fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp);
        SkipComments(fp);
    } else
        fseek(fp, -1, SEEK_CUR);
}

PGMData* readPGM(FILE *pgmFile, PGMData *data)
{
    char version[3];
    int i, j;
    int lo, hi;

    fgets(version, sizeof(version), pgmFile);
    if (strcmp(version, "P5")) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Wrong file type!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    SkipComments(pgmFile);
    fscanf(pgmFile, "%d", &(data->col));
    SkipComments(pgmFile);
    fscanf(pgmFile, "%d", &(data->row));
    SkipComments(pgmFile);
    fscanf(pgmFile, "%d", &(data->max_gray));
    fgetc(pgmFile);

    data->matrix = allocate_dynamic_matrix(data->row, data->col);

    if (data->max_gray > 255)
        for (i = 0; i < data->row; ++i)
            for (j = 0; j < data->col; ++j) {
                hi = fgetc(pgmFile);
                lo = fgetc(pgmFile);
                data->matrix[i][j] = (hi << 8) + lo;
            }
    else
        for (i = 0; i < data->row; ++i)
            for (j = 0; j < data->col; ++j) {
                lo = fgetc(pgmFile);
                data->matrix[i][j] = lo;
            }

    fclose(pgmFile);
    return data;

}
 /*and for writing*/

void writePGM(const char *filename, const PGMData *data)
{
    FILE *pgmFile;
    int i, j;
    int hi, lo;

    pgmFile = fopen(filename, "wb");
    if (pgmFile == NULL) {
        perror("cannot open file to write");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    fprintf(pgmFile, "P5 ");
    fprintf(pgmFile, "%d %d ", data->col, data->row);
    fprintf(pgmFile, "%d ", data->max_gray);

    if (data->max_gray > 255) {
        for (i = 0; i < data->row; ++i) {
            for (j = 0; j < data->col; ++j) {
                hi = HI(data->matrix[i][j]);
                lo = LO(data->matrix[i][j]);
                fputc(hi, pgmFile);
                fputc(lo, pgmFile);
            }

        }
    } else {
        for (i = 0; i < data->row; ++i)
            for (j = 0; j < data->col; ++j) {
                lo = LO(data->matrix[i][j]);
                fputc(lo, pgmFile);
            }
    }

    fclose(pgmFile);
    deallocate_dynamic_matrix(data->matrix, data->row);
}

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    PGMData *initialImage, *finalImage;
    int **initialMatrix=NULL, **finalMatrix=NULL;
    int n=atoi(argv[4]);
    int i, j, k, l, counter;
    int *buffer=NULL;
    //Time count
    clock_t start, end;
    double cpu_time_used;

    start = clock();
    if ( argc != 5 ) /* argc should be 5 for correct execution */
    {
        /* We print argv[0] assuming it is the program name */
        printf( "usage: %s filename", argv[0] );
    }
    else
    {
        // We assume argv[1] is a filename to open
        FILE *file = fopen( argv[1], "r" );

        /* fopen returns 0, the NULL pointer, on failure */
        if ( !file )
        {
            printf( "Could not open file\n" );
        }
        else
        {   initialImage = (PGMData *)malloc(1 * sizeof(PGMData));
            initialImage = readPGM (file, initialImage);
            initialMatrix = (int **)malloc(initialImage->row * sizeof(int*));
            for(i = 0; i < initialImage->row; i++) {
                initialMatrix[i] = (int *)malloc(initialImage->col * sizeof(int));
            }
            finalMatrix = (int **)malloc(initialImage->row * sizeof(int*));
            for(i = 0; i < initialImage->row; i++) {
                finalMatrix[i] = (int *)malloc(initialImage->col * sizeof(int));
            }
            if (initialMatrix == NULL || finalMatrix == NULL) {
                puts ("Unable to allocate memory for matrix");
            }
            for (i = 0; i < initialImage->row; i++){
                for (j = 0; j < initialImage->col; j++){
                    initialMatrix[i][j] = initialImage->matrix[i][j];
                }
            }
            buffer = (int *) malloc(n * n * sizeof (int));
            if (buffer == NULL) {
                puts ("Unable to allocate memory for buffer");
            }
            for (i = 0; i < initialImage->row; i++){
                for (j = 0; j < initialImage->col; j++){
                    counter = 0;
                    for (k = -(n/2); k <= n/2; k++){
                        for (l = -(n/2); l <= n/2; l++){
    /*top left corner*/     if (i-k <= 0 && j-l <= 0) {
                                buffer[counter]=initialMatrix[0][0];
                            }
    /*left side*/       else if (i-k <= 0 && j-l >= 0 && j-l <= initialImage->col-1) {
                                buffer[counter]=initialMatrix[0][j-l];
                            }
    /*top side*/       else if (j-l <= 0 && i-k >= 0 && i-k <= initialImage->row-1) {
                                buffer[counter]=initialMatrix[i-k][0];
                            }
    /*bottom left corner*/     else if (j-l <= 0 && i-k >= initialImage->row-1) {
                                buffer[counter]=initialMatrix[initialImage->row-1][0];
                            }
    /*top right corner*/    else if (i-k <= 0 && j-l >= initialImage->col-1) {
                                buffer[counter]=initialMatrix[0][initialImage->col-1];
                            }
    /*bottom side*/       else if (i-k >= initialImage->row-1 && j-l >= 0 && j-l <=initialImage->col-1) {
                                buffer[counter]=initialMatrix[initialImage->row-1][j-l];
                            }
    /*right side*/  else if (j-l >= initialImage->col-1 && i-k >= 0 && i-k <=initialImage->row-1) {
                                buffer[counter]=initialMatrix[i-k][initialImage->col-1];
                            }
    /*bottom right corner*/   else if (j-l >= initialImage->col-1 && i-k >= initialImage->row-1) {
                                buffer[counter]=initialMatrix[initialImage->row-1][initialImage->col-1];
                            }
    /*rest*/              else {
                                buffer[counter]=initialMatrix[i-k][j-l];
                            }
                            counter++;
                        }
                    }
                    if(!strcmp(argv[3], "ins")) {
                        insertion_sort (buffer, n*n);
                    }
                    else if(!strcmp(argv[3], "qs")) {
                        quick_sort (buffer, n*n);
                    }
                    else if(!strcmp(argv[3], "cnt")) {
                        counting_sort (buffer, n*n);
                    }
                    else {
                        puts ("Unknown sorting algorithm");
                    }
                    finalMatrix[i][j] = buffer [n * n/2];
                }
            }
            finalImage = (PGMData *)malloc(1 * sizeof(PGMData));
            finalImage->col=initialImage->col;
            finalImage->row=initialImage->row;
            finalImage->max_gray = initialImage->max_gray;
            finalImage->matrix = finalMatrix;
            writePGM (argv[2], finalImage);
            deallocate_dynamic_matrix(initialMatrix, initialImage->row);
            deallocate_dynamic_matrix(initialImage->matrix, initialImage->row);
            free(buffer);
            free(initialImage);
            free(finalImage);
        }
    }
    end = clock();
    cpu_time_used = ((double) (end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf ("Execution time: %f seconds\n", cpu_time_used);
}
```

Comment: Did you test the loading / saving functions independently ? (I mean, deactivate the blurring code, and just write a program meant to copy the image). I suspect that the problem comes from the way ASCII file are handled in Windows that may be different from Linux (maybe in SkipComments())

Comment: Replace `FILE *file = fopen( argv[1], "r" );` with `FILE *file = fopen( argv[1], "rb" );`, because otherwise the Windows C library does newline conversion mangling your data (byte values 10 and 13, in particular).

Comment: @NominalAnimal: Why would that matter? *.pgm is in practice a text file. It's read by fscanf("%d")  which is a giveaway.

Comment: in main() the 'usage' statement does not match the requirement for argc to be 5.

Comment: in C, do not cast the returned value from malloc() and family of functions.  because the returned value is a void* type so can be assigned to any other pointer and the casting makes for maintenance problems and debugging problems.

Comment: in this pair of lines: `initialImage = (PGMData *)malloc(1 * sizeof(PGMData));
            initialImage = readPGM (file, initialImage);` your setting a pointer to allocated memory, then writing on that pointer.  This results in the original pointer being lost.  resulting in a memory leak.

Comment: when calling malloc() always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.   in the posted code, many of the returned values from malloc() are not being checked.  a Malloc failure would result in accessing memory at address 0, resulting undefined behaviour and leading to a seg fault event

Comment: in this kind of statement: `finalImage = (PGMData *)malloc(1 * sizeof(PGMData));` there is no need to multiply by 1.  Infact the multiplication just clutters the code and has absolutely no effect on the value passed to malloc()

Comment: there seems to be some duplicate calls to free() regarding the rows of the image.

Comment: @MSalters: Only the header is in text. The grayscale data is binary, and read using `fgetc()`.

Comment: @user3629249: `initialImage` (actually `data`) is unmodified in the `readPGM()` file, which means there is no memory leak.  Looking at the `deallocate_dynamic_matrix()` function, I don't see any double frees either.

Comment: @NominalAnimal your suggestion worked just fine. Changing that made the program give the right result. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @GRC: Sometimes, the tag-wiki and/or tag-excerpt is actually unreliable. So [sanity-checking it](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bblur%5d%20-%5bcss%2A%5d%20-%5bjs%5d%20-%5bangular%2A%5d%20-%5bjquery%5d%20-%5bhtml%2A%5d%20is%3aq) is appropriate, which led me to roll back here. (If you aren't sure, ask on meta, where everyone interested can chime in.)